# How can I extract a closed zip with python

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to extract a closed zip with the use of the ZipFile module but:

> "The open(), read() and extract() methods can take a filename or a ZipInfo object. "

```
def ExtractZip(zipFile, path):
   zipfile.ZipFile.open(zipFile, 'r')
   zipFile.extractall(path)
```

This is my code, it returns an error. (I have a zipfile I closed before running this function with `.close()` and I cant delete it)
How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: 2.7 python version

Comment: What do you mean by a "closed" ZIP file?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. This is not the best way to use the zipfile module although there is nothing wrong with your approach
> 2. You are not storing the zipfile object in any variable hence you aren't accessing it

How your function should look

```
import zipfile

def extract_zip(path: str):
    with zipfile.Zipfile(path) as file:
        file.extractall()
```

This extracts the zipfile into the same directory it is in. While this is better is because it uses a context manager that automatically closes the file for you after you're done working with it.

If you would like to extract the zipfile into another folder

```
import zipfile
    
def extract_zip(path: str, extract_to: str):
    with zipfile.Zipfile(path) as file:
        file.extractall(path=extract_to)
```

This will extract the file into the folder you specify. Also, with this approach you do not need to specify the mode as read as that is done by default.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file is `Archive.zip`:

Then, do this:

```
import zipfile
f = zipfile.ZipFile('Archive.zip')
f.extractall()
```

That's it. You can also provide an optional `path` argument to `extractall` if you want to place the contents somewhere else.

More info can be found in the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall).

Comment: does not answer OPs question

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) to access archives.

```py
import zipfile
zippedArchive = zipfile.ZipFile('Scripts.zip')
print zippedArchive.open("Scripts/PlayPauseYouTube.scpt").read()
```

will print the contents of the `PlayPauseYouTube.scpt` file.

If you want to *extract* all the files inside the zip archive, as in to another location, you can use [`zipfile.extractall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall)

> ```
> ZipFile.extractall([path[, members[, pwd]]])
> ```
>
> Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory. `path` specifies a different directory to extract to. `members` is optional and must be a subset of the list returned by [`zipfile.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist). `pwd` is the password used for encrypted files.

```
import zipfile
zippedArchive = zipfile.ZipFile('Scripts.zip')
zippedArchive.extractall()
```

Comment: does not answer OPs question

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, based on all ZipFile examples, you need to store the archive in a variable

```
def ExtractZip(zipFile, path):
   archive = zipfile.ZipFile.open(zipFile, 'r')
   archive.extractall(path)
```